# Как добавить поиск по listview

Tags: java, android, listview, поиск

Добрый день более опытные коллеги.
Научите пожалуйста, как добавить поиск на страницу с listview
Данные заполняются с Firebase Realtime, объём данных более 500+ записей, без поиска плохо.
Читал пробовал разные примеры, но всегда крашит приложение.

прикладываю код класса:

```
     package com.krascsm.csm;
        
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        
        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        
        import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
        
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        
        public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ListView listView;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private List<String> listData;
        private List<User> listTemp;
            private DatabaseReference mDataBase;
            private String USER_KEY = "People";
        
        
            public void mainclick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            public void timeclick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Times.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            public void workclick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, WorkPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            public void contactclick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            public void regclick(View view){
                /*
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, reg.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        */
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReadActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        
        
        
        
        
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.read_layout);
                init();
                getDataFromDB();
                setOnClickItem();
            }
        
        
        
        public void init() {
                listView=findViewById(R.id.listview);
                listData = new ArrayList<>();
            listTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mDataBase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USER_KEY);
        
        }
        
        private void getDataFromDB() {
        
            ValueEventListener vListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(listData.size() > 0) listData.clear();
                    if(listTemp.size() > 0) listTemp.clear();
        
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    listData.add(user.fio);
                        listTemp.add(user);
        
                    }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
        
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        
                }
            };
            mDataBase.addValueEventListener(vListener);
        }
        
        private void setOnClickItem() {
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    User user = listTemp.get(i);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ReadActivity.this, ShowActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_NAME,user.name);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_SEC_NAME,user.sec_name);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_EMAIL,user.email);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_FIO,user.fio);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_DOLJNOST,user.doljnost);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_PHONE,user.phone);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_VNPHONE,user.vnphone);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_MOBILE,user.mobile);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_STATUS,user.status);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_OTDEL,user.otdel);
                        intent.putExtra(Constant.USER_CABINET,user.cabinet);
                          startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        }
```

также код Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView23" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Справочник"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/listview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам следует использовать SearchView в xml, после чего отслеживать изменение в SearchView.

```
SearchText = findViewById(R.id.serchaview);

SearchText.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                text-from_SearchView = query;
                 //do something
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                text-from_SearchView = newText;
                //do something
                return false;
            }
        });
```

после этого искать в Firebase нужные вам записи. Каждый раз как вы изменяете текст в SearchView делать запрос на поиск нужные записи.

Comment: Дело в том что я разбирал подключение и вывод firebase по видеоурокам. Можете  подробнее описать с примером

Comment: Поиск осуществляется по введенным словам, но мы можем поставить слушателя изменения текста. Например есть два города "Москва" и "Минск", при вводе буквы "М" нам должно выдать два города, так как они оба начинаются с одной буквы, а вот после ввода следующей буквы, например "и". нам покажет только "Минск".  В моем случае у меня есть сервер связанный с БД и я проверяю каждую строку в БД согласно полученной информации. В java есть метод startsWith().  [Тут](http://proglang.su/java/strings-startswith) подробнее написано.

Comment: добавил TextListener и через getFilter получилось искать текст)))) Всем спасибо

Comment: Обнаружил интересный момент:   ```editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });``` при нажатии открывается ВСЕГДА ПЕРВАЯ ЗАПИСЬ